# mysqldump --no-data: how to ensure consistent order of lines in dump file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am creating a dump file using the MariaDB version of `mysqldump` like this:

```
mysqldump \
  --no-data \
  --compact \
  --skip-triggers \
  --no-tablespaces \
  --default-character-set=utf8 \
  --host="$MYSQL_HOST" \
  --user="$MYSQL_USERNAME" \
  --password="$MYSQL_PASSWORD" \
  "$MYSQL_DATABASE" |
  sed '/character_set_client/d' |
  sed 's/InnoDB.*/InnoDB;/g' \
    >"schema.sql"
```

This always outputs the tables in the same order, but it list all columns (other than `id`) for each table in random order.

So, the first run might output this...

```
create TABLE `ONE` ( 
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` ( 
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

...and on the second run, it might produce something like this:

```
create TABLE `ONE` ( 
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` ( 
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How can I configure `mysqldump` (or MySQL etc for that matter) to always list the columns in the same order?

(I'm aware the best option might be to just pipe the result through a shell script that sorts it as required. I've asked about this in [a different StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77944976/text-file-how-to-sort-adjacent-lines-that-have-the-same-level-of-indentation) with different tags.)

Comment: I haven't observed it, but it definately is a bug if so. The order of a table is strict. The `mariadb-dump` (previously `mysqldump` named) is straight from the `show create table` SQL without processing take no the output. Which  MariaDB server version are you using?

Comment: Thanks @danblack. `mysqldump --version` returns `Ver 10.19 Distrib 10.3.39-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`. The dump occurs after all migrations are run using `sequelize-cli`. With each build, the database is created again, the migrations are run again, and the dump is dumped again. The documentation for `sequelize-cli` indicates the order is deterministic, but I'm wondering if it might not be, in some subtle way.

Comment: I doubt that this is a tool bug. Check tables structures carefully - they should alter in practice.

Comment: In relational theory, there's no reason why columns should be ordered in any particular way. But in standard SQL, there definitely is a deterministic order to columns. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table shows the ORDINAL_POSITION of each column, and this determines the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE, which is what mysqldump uses. I'm wondering if your sequelize migrations are running in a random order, so they produce a different table each time.

Comment: Yes, that was it @BillKarwin. Digging through the migrations, I found that plenty had mistakes in their use of promises, meaning they were guaranteed to create the same columns, but not guaranteed to create them in the same order. Fixing all those errors resulted in a dump.sql file that always has exactly the same form.

Comment: To clarify, the migrations were running in the expected order, but many of them contained commands that were not guaranteed to run in the same order.

Comment: Not related to your question, but FYI MariaDB 10.3 has been out of support since May 2023. Cf. https://endoflife.date/mariadb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments above, a hunch was that the migrations were adding columns to tables one by one in an unpredictable order. This turned out to be true because the migrations were running asynchronously via promises.

If the order is important, it's better to control the order of operations by waiting for each one to finish before executing the next one.